# Linear Transformation from $\mathbb{R}^{0}$ to $\mathbb{R}^{1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I'm trying to understand the following:
Let
T be a linear transformation from $\mathbb{R}^{0}$ to $\mathbb{R}^{1}$

What is the size of its standard matrix?

Option $A$: $1\times 0$

Option $B$: $0\times 1$

I don't really understand these answers anyway. How can there be a matrix with a row with no entries, or vice versa, no rows and one entry?

Would really appreciate some help, thanks in advance!

Comment: it's more convention then else, really. Just think the standard dimension of a linear map $R^n\to R^m$ and then substitute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a linear transformation $T\colon\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^m$ the dimension of its associated matrix is $m\times n$. In your case $n=1$ and $m=0$ and so its option $A$ by definition/convention.

However, for $n=0$ or $m=0$ this is not really a useful thing to talk about. In fact, there is only one linear map $\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^0$ and also only one linear map $\mathbb R^0\to\mathbb R^m$ defined in the first case by $v\mapsto0$ for all $v\in\mathbb R^n$ and by $0\mapsto0$ in the second case ($\mathbb R^0=\{0\}$ by definition).

Comment: The only thing it could be useful to, is when you compose application, since you have to have the right dimensions

Comment: @Exodd Care to elaborate? I'm not sure if I can follow.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with a defintion of matrix. A real matrix $A$ of type $m\times n$ is a function:
$$A\colon \{1,2,\ldots,m\}\times \{1,2,\ldots,n\}\to \mathbb R.$$

By choosing bases, there is one-to-one correspondence between real matrices of type $m\times n$ and linear operators $\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^m$. The choice what columns and what rows are is arbitrary but is made such that matrix multiplication is consistent with function composition. Thus, it is standard that dimension of the codomain is the number of rows, while the dimension of the domain is the number of columns.

So, if you want to represent linear transformation $\mathbb R^0\to \mathbb R^1$, its corresponding matrix is by the standard convention of size $1\times 0$.

However, thinking of rows and columns kind of breaks down in this case. So, let us think purely of definition what a matrix of type $1\times 0$ is. It is a function $$A\colon \{1\}\times \emptyset\to\mathbb R.$$ More conveniently, the set $\{1\}\times \emptyset$ is equal to the empty set $\emptyset$, and our matrix is therefore a function $$A\colon \emptyset \to \mathbb R.$$ For any set $X$ there exists unique function $\emptyset\to X$ called empty function, so our matrix $A$ is just an empty function.

On the other hand, there is also unique linear transformation $\mathbb R^0 \to \mathbb R^1$ given by $0\mapsto 0$. This is forced since linear transformations must preserve zero vectors, and $\mathbb R^0$ as a set is a singleton and as a vector space it is the real space that consists only of the $0$ vector.

Nothing changes if we consider matrices of type $n\times 0$ or $0\times n$. There is always only one matrix of such type and it is empty function. The corrseponding linear transformation is the zero map: transformation that sends all vectors in the domain to the zero vector in the codomain. I don't think it makes much sense to talk about rows and columns in this case.